# undefined reference to 'sqrt' when trying to use make command

Tags: reference, makefile, undefined, gpx

I've been trying to compile some code which will allow me to convert gcode to x3g for my 3d printer, but it throws me the following whenever I attempt to run 'make.'

```
sudo make
[sudo] password for kipinaac: 
cc -c -w getopt.c -o getopt.o
cc -c -w gpx.c -o gpx.o
cc -c -w gpx-main.c -o gpx-main.o
cc -lm getopt.o gpx.o gpx-main.o -o gpx
gpx.o: In function `magnitude':
gpx.c:(.text+0x1c1f): undefined reference to `sqrt'
gpx.o: In function `mm_to_steps':
gpx.c:(.text+0x224d): undefined reference to `round'
gpx.c:(.text+0x2274): undefined reference to `round'
gpx.c:(.text+0x229b): undefined reference to `round'
gpx.c:(.text+0x22ef): undefined reference to `round'
gpx.c:(.text+0x2353): undefined reference to `round'
gpx.o:gpx.c:(.text+0x2397): more undefined references to `round' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [gpx] Error 1
```

I checked to ensure that there is a reference to  within gpx.c too. I've picked up that it might have something to do with linking from some other threads, but they all explicitly call gcc rather than using make. Also, to be clear, there is a Makefile already provided.

Comment: Libraries (`-lm`) after object files.  Move the `-lm` to the end and you will be OK.

Comment: I edited the Makefile to include the libraries after the object files and it compiled correctly. The Makefile was provided on Github and there were numerous videos showing successful installs, so something tells me that it should have worked without this step. Any ideas?

Comment: It only worked by accident — some versions of GCC and its linker will note the contents of libraries listed before any object files; others (including yours) will only use the library if it supplies any symbols that it needs supplied at the time when it is scanned.  When the library is before the object files, it doesn't satisfy the only symbol the linker is looking for — `main` — so it is ignored as irrelevant.  The only safe way to work is 'libraries after object files'.  That works with static and shared libraries, with both styles of linker.

Answer (score 1):

<sup>*Transferring comments to answer to allow closure of question.*</sup>

Put libraries (`-lm`) after the object files on the command line. Move the `-lm` to the end and you will be OK.

> I edited the Makefile to include the libraries after the object files and it compiled correctly. The Makefile was provided on Github and there were numerous videos showing successful installs, so something tells me that it should have worked without this step. Any ideas?

It only worked by accident — some versions of GCC and its linker will note the contents of libraries listed before any object files; others (including yours) will only use the library if it supplies any symbols that it needs supplied at the time when it is scanned. When the library is before the object files, it doesn't satisfy the only symbol the linker is looking for — `main` — so it is ignored as irrelevant. The only safe way to work is 'libraries after object files'. That works with static and shared libraries, with both styles of linker.